# Delay the communication between two threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, communication

I have two threads (I am using `pthreads` on GNU/Linux). Now they are sharing information using global variables (I know, it's not nice). At the end of each cycle they have to send the value of 5 variables (`doubles`) to the other thread.
I would like to introduce a fixed time delay in their communication channel,

i.e.

> thread1 (1kHz) <---> 10ms <---> thread2 (1kHz)

I was thinking that, at each cycle, I could create a thread which reads the value, sleep for 10ms, then forward it to the other thread and then dies.
This will make the system create 2 threads every cycle, one for each direction of the communication channel (2 threads per millisecond).

Is there any other intelligent way of simulating a delay in the communication?

**UPDATE**: I do not want to synchronize the communication of the threads but add a delay between them.
If thread1 writes something at time 1s the other thread should be able to read it only at time 1s + 10ms.

Comment: Why do you need to create new threads every time?

Comment: Do you want this delay as a means of synchronization? If so then it's a terrible idea. If not then why the delay?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I **need** to add a delay in order to reproduce communication delays in a network.

Comment: @HonkyTonk: I don't know, it was my first guess. I'm here to ask for a better solution.

Comment: You could use synchronization to set a time-based variable in the writer thread and only check the others int he reader if the desired time has passed (compared to the value of the time-based variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a performance problem, so make it simple.  No need for complex data structures, extra threads, etc.

Make a struct for your data, add a timestamp field to it.

Make an array to hold at least 10 of your structs.  Go for 100 to be safe.  Not going to use a lot of memory here, so who cares.   Heck you could malloc it whenever it needed to grow.

Each thread has one such array, and a count of items in the array.

When a thread is ready to send data, do two things:

1. Check the timestamp of the first item in it's array, and if old
   enough send that data to the other thread.  After sending, decrement
   the count and memmove the rest of the items in the array down one
   notch.
2. Add the current/new data to the end of the array with the
   current time stamp and increment the count.

Repeat for other thread.

Comment: You will still need some sort of thread synchronization mechanism for the data sending part

Comment: I agree, I was hoping the question was more about a way to have the messages take 10ms to get to the other thread.  A local FIFO solves that.  He will still need to use atomic ops or mutexes to synch the data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use mutexes to synchronize the communication between the two threads?

When the first thread needs to write the data, it acquires the mutex (so the other thread cannot read the data while the first updates it), updates the datam, then releases the mutex.  The other thread does a similar acquire/release method when it reads the data.

Comment: Seems like OP wants the global variables to act like a FIFO, and that this approach won't guarantee that behavior (couldn't the writer thread, for example, acquire the mutex, write the data, release the mutex, and then acquire the mutex again, before the reader thread got to it?)

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell from the question whether communication between the writer and reader threads needs to be reliable (as in: all messages sent by the writer thread guaranteed to be seen by the reader thread, in the correct order).  If so, and if you're using a single global structure as the shared data, you're essentially implementing a FIFO with a buffer size of 1.  It's easy to get inter-thread communication wrong, so I'd recommend looking at something like glib's [asynchronous queues](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html).  If you need to implement your own from scratch, looking at that code could be a good place to start.

Comment: The communication needs to be reliable, I'll have a look to the link! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a semaphore here?  You could have one thread wait on the semaphore, and have the other thread signal it when it's finished with it's critical section.

Comment: I don't want to make the thread wait, only the piece of information going from one thread to another. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @claudio If you want reliable communication between the threads, there has to be some mechanism for one thread to wait for the other.  It may not end up waiting in practice, depending on the timing, but the mechanism needs to be there to ensure correct behavior.  Otherwise what's to prevent, for example, the reader thread from reading while the writer thread is only half done writing?

Comment: @nighthawk Wouldn't you need two semaphores here?  This is the classic [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) with a buffer size of one, which is traditionally implemented with two binary semaphores (one that counts full slots, one that counts empty slots)

Comment: You're probably right - you'd need some method of preventing the consumer thread from working with data that's partially written.